# RoboMQ SSL Issue

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, mq

I'm using [RoboMQ](http://www.robomq.com) to build a MQ to MQ service over SSL. I've got a keystore (key.jks) and I'm setting the following system properties to configure the SSL:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
javax.net.ssl.trustStrore
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
```

However, our email server requires SSL and setting up SSL in this way in [RoboMQ](http://www.robomq.com) stops it from working - I guess because it overrides the default cacerts which has the certificates in that the email client needs.

How can I get these 2 things to play nicely together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - setting the above system properties will override cacerts JVM 
wide. You need to use a custom socket factory for the SSL MQ connections

The RoboMQ SDK provides support for this via:

```
com.am.robomq.sdk.camelSpring.RoboSSLSocketFactory
```

But the easiest way to build your Camel MQ endpoints is to use the MQ Connection Wizard:

http://www.robomq.com/product_manual/index.html#serviceBuilderPanel

It basically lets you to pick a connection factory from your connection palette
and then generates the Spring definitions needed by Camel.